# Eclipse plugin - is TableViewer suitable when multiple tables required

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin for a screen definition editor. The preview page will have multiple tables of different rows/columns definitions, the contents of each cell is effectively a control definition (i.e. Label, TextBox, etc). Some basic requirements of the preview are:

1. User selection on any cell publishes the control properties to another view.
2. The cell styling is applied depending upon the control type.

Currently using JFace TableViewers but have the following issues:
1. Only one TableViewer can be registered as a selection provider via the getSite().setSelectionProvider(). How to listen for selection changes on all my tables?
2. TableViewer does not appear to allow for cell styling.
3. Cell selection programatically handling with a TableCursor, but the cell in a previous table is still highlighted when I select another cell in another table.

Are there more suitable layouts to use than TableViewer for my purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding point #2, cell styling, TableViewers do allow for customization of the display of cell data.  [Take a look here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#jfacetable_styledlabelprovider%5D) for some ideas on how to get started with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this approach](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/emf/source/browse/org.eclipselabs.emf.addon/src/org/eclipselabs/emf/addon/viewers/SelectionProviderIntermediate.java?r=975cbb8ca9e16d9018edb0c2c5f7c9dd3cdab8b5) for supporting selection in multiple tables with some modification (add listener to each of your table viewers so if one of them is selected it automatically becomes the delegate).

Comment: Or alternatively check out SelectionProviderMediator - detailed here: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/viewsupport/SelectionProviderMediator.java